# Grouped data back to list using lambda c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

When i have grouped my data, how do i get it back to my **_data** variable? I cant seem to declare the **query** variable outside the If statement, i guess because its anonymous?

How do i achieve this?

Thanks!

```
public IActionResult Get(string area, string hobby)
    {
        var _data = _myContext.getData();

        _data = _data.Where(x => x.hobby == hobby).ToList();

        if (area == "All")
        {
            var query = _data
            .GroupBy(a => new
            {
                a.area
            })
            .Select(b => new
            {
                myDate = b.First().myDate,
                totalAmount = b.Sum(c => c.totalAmount)
            });
        }

        return Ok(_data);
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to return grouped data stored in `query` variable in case `area` is All?

Comment: Instead of `var query = _data ...` just write `_data = _data ...`

Comment: No, it returns nothing if i have it like this: _data = _data ...

Comment: The type of `_data` must be fixed unless you use `dynamic` (not recommended). You must decide what `_data` should be and then assign it. What type does `getData()` return? (It must be `List<T>` for some `T`.)  How is that compatible with grouped `T`?

Comment: What is the parameter `area` for?

Comment: Declaring it dynamic did the trick this time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign the grouped result to _data as you are using a anonymous type. If you want to just return the result to caller you can directly return within the if statement

```
 if (area == "All")
        {
            var query = _data
            .GroupBy(a => new
            {
                a.area
            })
            .Select(b => new
            {
                myDate = b.First().myDate,
                totalAmount = b.Sum(c => c.totalAmount)
            });

          return Ok(query);
        }
```

Comment: If i put return inside If statetment i get error from my IActionResult that it does not return a value.

Comment: @gFat3 What if you do `return Ok(query.ToList());`?